# How to fork actions in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have many sequence files and a workflow of actions to execute on each file. The workflow is the same for all file and the number of input file may vary. I'd like to execute the workflow on a bunch of input files (let's say 10 files) in parallel using the fork mechanism in Oozie. If the number of input files were fixed, I knew how many workflow I should execute and could easily write a fork, but as it may vary I do not know how I should write my fork. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: what is your workflow is running ? Java /Shell/Pig/MR ? in some of those cases you can control the parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write java oozie client that will accept number of files as parameter and have that many number of workflows to be invoked parallely and return on success of all workflow executions. Otherwise, You might have to programmatically generate workflow with desired number of fork branches.

Comment: Could you give me more details or provide me with an example please?